# How do I get this to return a double without converting to string

Tags: java, string, return, double

```
public double futureInvestmentValue(int years) {
    DecimalFormat dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces;
    dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    double futureInvestmentValue = deposit * Math.pow((1 + (AnnualInterestRate / 12)), years * 12);
    return dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces.format(futureInvestmentValue);
```

The errors i'm receiving are with the last line. It says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to double" 
It's asking me to change to public String.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your method signature, you declare the return type of the method as a double.

However, this line:

```
return dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces.format(futureInvestmentValue);
```

calls a method that returns a String. You have to decide the utility of this function and whether or not you need it to return a pre-formatted value or leave that responsibility to the caller.

Comment: How can I return as a double in decimal format. It seems that everytime I try to use the dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces.format(), i get the error.

Comment: The double data type isn't represented in a decimal format as you may think of it. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

The DecimalFormat format method is a utility method to get the print format representation of the double value that you specify when you instantiate it. 

The short answer is you can't return a double in decimal format.

Comment: So is this something i'd alter in the main() to change the double to decimal format?

Comment: @Jack Pavlov: No!  You're not "changing" anything.  A double is a double, a string is a string - and (as  Spencer Brett correctly told you) your method needs to pass one or the other.  BEST APPROACH: 1) keep "double" as `futureInvestmentValue()'s` return value (you *want* to return a "number"!), 2) Use a Java [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (similar to what you have above), whenever you actually want to *print* the value (e.g. to a console or GUI).

Answer (score 1):

```
public double futureInvestmentValue(int years) {
    // DecimalFormat dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces; // Don't need this
    // dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); // Don't need this, either
    double futureInvestmentValue = deposit * Math.pow((1 + (AnnualInterestRate / 12)), years * 12); // This is *ALL* you need!
    //return dfWithTwoDecimalPlaces.format(futureInvestmentValue); // Nope: don't return a string!
    return futureInvestmentValue; // return the double!
```

Comment: How would I return the value as a double in format (0.00) instead of "1383.422759428736" 

Is this something I should do in the main()?

Comment: "Double" doesn't *HAVE* a "format".  It's just a NUMBER, an abstract "value".  "Printing" - how you *REPRESENT* that value - is *INDEPENDENT* of the value itself.  Use a "format" statement anywhere you want. Look [here](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for two completely different alternatives. See also the Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html